# Wait till file is uploaded async to start next task

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, async-await

I need to process an XML file once it is uploaded. How do I check if the files are completely uploaded before I start the new method to do work on the file?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
    var uploads = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        if (file.Length > 0)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, fileName), FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
    ProcessFile();
    return View("NewProject");
}

private void ProcessFile()
{
     //Do WORK
}
```

Right now it starts to Process the file while it's still being uploaded. How can I wait till upload is finished and check that the file is uploaded before Processing the File?

Comment: Any luck? Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link [FileStream Reading](http://www.csharp-examples.net/filestream-read-file/). As per your problem, you need to do a length check for the contents of the file and when all the content is read, do the await call.